# Angular replace one word in many translation depend on flag

Tags: angularjs, translation, angular-translate

I have problem with one task. I am using:

```
"angular": "~1.2.16",
"angular-translate": "2.1.0",
```

The problem is that I need to change for example word 'bug' to 'issue' in all my translation which contain this word, depend on the toggle button. Is there an easy way to do this? I thought about some listener which will replace this word after translate finished. Or maybe there is a way to put parameter into translation string and replace it with some global variable which will hold word I need.

Could you give me some advice here, maybe provide some examples how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

'angular-translate' is dummy as tree: it has key-value pairs picked from corresponding language object and maps key to values. So if you use angular-translate module, you have js object, that describes your dictionary. In each of this objects you should to create pair with key 'BUG' and value 'bug' or 'issue' depend on language.

Comment: Sorry but, I do not understand your answer. In angular I have translation file en-gb.json where I store my translation "key" : "translation". I want to replace string 'bug' in translation to 'issue' not creating new key, with new translation.

Comment: So why not to create another pair like "ISSUE": "Issue" and pick correct one when you need it:   {{ someCondition ? 'BUG' : 'ISSUE' | translation }} ?

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am not sure o this solution but I will try and give feedback about it.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your example but I have 300 translations to change, and before I do it I have to thing twice. If I use your example, I will mark your answer as correct.